# universal quantification and vacuous entailment in OWL using Protege

Tags: owl, protege

I am trying understand cases where vacuous entailment occurs due to use of universal quantification in Protege. That is, axioms of the form:

`A rel *only* B`

Here is my setup:

I have created an ontology that (more or less) follows the one described in this Ontogenesis article:

http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/1260

It consists of an `owns` relation and two high level disjoint classes: `person` and `pet`.

Under the pet class, I have three primitive disjoint classes: `dog`, `elephant`, and `newt`.

Below the person class, I have a defined class `pet owner`, defined as follows:

`'pet owner' equivalent_to person and (owns only pet)`

Lastly, I have created and individual person, named `person 1`, that does not own any pets.

Universal quantification:

My understanding of universal quantification is that the `only` quantifier describes those individuals that only have relationships to individuals of a specific class. This entails that individuals that do not have any relationships to another individual would also be described by universal quantification.

In my example, I thought `person 1` would be inferred to be a `pet owner`, since `person 1` does not `own` any `pets` or stand in any other relationships. However, when I run the reasoner (HermiT and Pellet), this does not turn out to be the case. `Person 1` is not inferred to be a member of `pet owner`.

So, it seems that I am not understanding universal quantification. Can someone please help me?

Comment: This is probably the most philsophical question I have encountered on SO today.  I wish I understood what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you didn't take into account Open World Assumption (OWA). By OWA the ontology only contains facts that are known; there might be other facts. If you say nothing about the things `person 1` owns, it doesn't mean that it owns nothing. It might own other things, that are not in the ontology. So your universal restriction may **prevent** someone to be a pet owner (in case they own something that is not a pet, and the corresponding axiom is in the ontology). To make someone a pet owner, you might 'close' the information about it, e.g. saying that known pets are the only things that person owns. For this you may use `owns only {pet1, pet2, pet3}` construction.

Comment: Thanks. Once I accounted for OWA, I got the result I expected. Specifically, I made the dog, elephant, and newt classes disjoint, and I defined the class to be `dog or elephant or newt`.